# Date And Day of week, in url (Contextual filter in views)

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm looking for a way to only show contents related to a **specific date** And **specific day in the week**.

for example:
mysite.com/2014/03/02
mysite.com/yesterday

Is there a way to achieve this ? Maybe with views or hooks or something custom ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not same as your requirement, but this can help you.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9340/how-to-create-a-drop-down-menu-for-monthly-archives/106053#106053